# Prerender SPA Plugin does not work with nested routes

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-router, prerender

I'm a using Vue 2, Webpack, vue-router and Prerender Spa Plugin.

I'm facing an issue when I try to prerender my nested routes.

The plug-in works fine for the routes `'/'` and `'/first-level'`.
But when I add a nested routes `'/first-level/second-level'`, the output `html` is the same as the `index.html` for the `'/'` route.

Here is my webpack conf :

[image]

Does anyone encoutered the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your routing mode?
Change your routing mode to history

```js
const router: Router = new Router({
  mode: 'history', 
  routes, 
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) { 
    if (savedPosition) { 
      return savedPosition; 
    } else { 
      return { x: 0, y: 0 } 
    } 
  } 
})
```

Comment: can you type the code in your answer please? it's easier to see, more user-friendly

Comment: const router: Router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    } else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  }
})

Answer (score 0):

@Sandwell, I'm not sure its a general problem with the plugin.

I use version `^3.3.0` of the plugin and it works fine here. Though "this" is not an answer, this is just to tell you that its possible using the plugin.

I'd like to help you more if this problem still persists.

Cheers.

[image]